# Librosa Python Library Integration in iOS

Tags: python, ios, swift, coreml, librosa

I am looking for a way to integrate Librosa sound analysis library(written in Python) in an iOS project. Any insight will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The links to the Librosa library -
https://librosa.org/
https://github.com/librosa/librosa

Answer (score 1):

**[You can try this LINK](https://github.com/dhrebeniuk/RosaKit)**

There have a swift library created by github/dhrebeniuk, which is actually the iOS version for LibRosa.

Main goal of this library :

```
- Generate Spectrogram for visualisations.
- Preprocessing steps for most Machine Learning models in Sound Recognition Sphere.
```

Comment: I have already checked this repo, it doesn't have mfcc feature extraction part but it's under development.

Comment: I added this feature new new release